# C - Read file to Doubly Linked List got segmentation fault

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am reading from `txt` file into a doubly linked list. The codes can do storing data into Nodes, but when I let it go through the linked list, it got a segmentation fault.

Could you guys please tell what has been wrong with the code, thank you!

This is the data structure:

```
typedef struct telephoneBookNode {
    int id;
    char name[NAME_LENGTH];
    char telephone[TELEPHONE_LENGTH];
    struct telephoneBookNode * previousNode;
    struct telephoneBookNode * nextNode;
} TelephoneBookNode;

typedef struct telephoneBookList {
    TelephoneBookNode * head;
    TelephoneBookNode * tail;
    TelephoneBookNode * current;
    unsigned size;
} TelephoneBookList;
```

This is the code to create linked list:

```
TelephoneBookList * createTelephoneBookList(char entry[]) {
    TelephoneBookList* aList = NULL;
    TelephoneBookNode* aNode = NULL;
    char *tokens;

    TelephoneBookNode *(*create)() = createTelephoneBookNode;
    aNode = (*create)();

    tokens = strtok(entry, ", ");
    aNode->id = atoi(tokens);

    tokens = strtok(NULL, ", ");
    strcpy(aNode->name, tokens);

    tokens = strtok(NULL, ", ");
    strcpy(aNode->telephone, tokens); //Fine until here

    //Do I need this line?
    //aList = (TelephoneBookList*) malloc(aList->size + 1) * sizeof aList);

    if (aList->head == NULL) {
        aNode->nextNode = NULL;
        aNode->previousNode = NULL;

        aList->current = aNode;
        aList->head = aNode;
        aList->tail = aNode;
    } else {
        aList->tail->nextNode = aNode;
        aNode->previousNode = aList->tail;
    }
    return aList;
}

TelephoneBookNode * createTelephoneBookNode() {
    TelephoneBookNode* aNode;

    aNode = (TelephoneBookNode*) malloc(sizeof *aNode);
    return aNode;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Do I need this line?
//aList = (TelephoneBookList*) malloc(aList->size + 1) * sizeof aList);
```

Yes. Yes you do need that line. Otherwise the next line

```
if (aList->head == NULL) {
```

will dereference a null pointer.

Though you already do that in the commented out `malloc` call, dereference a null pointer, with `aList->size + 1`.

The correct line should be

```
aList = malloc(sizeof *aList);
```

---

And since you create the list from scratch in the function, there is no need to check if it is empty or not, it will *always* be empty. More importantly, the `malloc` call will not initialize the memory it allocates, so using that memory (for example in an expression like `aList->head == NULL`) will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Allocate the list structure. And then initialize it as if it was empty. And don't forget to initialize the `size` member as well.

Comment: Note that even with this line, malloc() will not initialize aList->head to NULL, and it's undefined behaviour to even reference its value. calloc() is what you're looking for, probably.

Answer (score 0):

Your `createTelephoneBookNode` function does not initialize the node that it created. malloc() assigns it a memory block that's probably not been initialized with zeros, and as a result, the nextNode and previousNode pointers contain garbage. Either set them both to NULL, or allocate your memory with calloc().